# Cant access to Cpanel or WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a problem with a IT person, and seems he did things with the access to Cpanel and WHM.

I have access to the serve via SSH.

I'm trying to change the passwords with `/scripts/chpass` for Cpanel, but it doesn't work.

Also, I'm trying to access to WHM with `root` user and ssh's password, but it doesn't work.

Also, I try to change it with `passwd`, `sudo passwd` or `passwd root` and put in a new password, but also, it doesn't work.

Also, I try with `whmapi1 user=root password=mynewpassword`, and guess... it doesn't work.

What I'm missing?

How I can change access?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting WHM and cPanel login screen? What is the exact error you get while trying to login into WHM as root user?